# continues printing in crystal report in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

i am trying to make a software for inventory and invoice.
i am using vb.net 4.5, SQL-server 2005 and crystal report.
my problem is that sometimes items are increases more then page size and i want them all to print on a single paper.
i am using TVS RP 3160 thermal printer. i want the paper width 7 cm and height according to the items.
i create two pages ,now i want that when the first page finish then the printer continues to print second page from details section or report footer.
i want to print my bill properly ,i don't want to print two different bills.
hope you understand my problem. please give your suggestions.
I appreciate if you can provide me some tutorial or source code for this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using SubReport in Crystal report.  You can design your first page at first subreport and then the next page on the other sub report.  Your main report will contain your one or more subreport on its footer section (you can use as many subreport as you want but also consider the performance impact).

[Here is a tutorial](http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_subreport.htm)

Comment: my all items are in details section and the subtotal and total and other important items are in section footer.

Comment: that is not a problem, create a new report as a container of your subreport and import your current existing report as a subreport.

Comment: Yes it will, just imagine your existing reports as a subreport and you want to display or print them in single report just create a new report and put them inside your main report footer section (one footer section per subreport)

Comment: and what size i should set for my report ? i want width 7cm but height will be set according to the items ok. All the problem is started because i cant re-size the page height according to the items. if there is any way to do this , i appreciate your help, i think it will be much batter ,but i will also try subreport and then post result here. thanks for your help Jade.

Comment: if you installed your printer driver in your pc, then you can select that printer in your crystal report, select the paper that has a 7cm in width (usually it is continuous paper)